# "Virtual" is qualifier or keyword in C++?

Tags: c++

"Virtual" is qualifier or keyword in C++?

Answer (score 13):

`virtual` is a *keyword* and a *function-specifier*. It's not a qualifier. C++ only talks about *cv-qualifiers* (i.e. `const` and `volatile`); the only other uses of the word qualifier refer to scope resolution prefixes (i.e. global `::` and `ns::` and `class_name::` prefixes) in qualified ids.

Comment: And the C++ spec talks about a template name to be "explicitly qualified by the template arguments". It also uses the term during overload resolution to say "x.foo" is a qualified call and "foo" (as well as "x::foo") etc is an unqualified call. I find that confusing though :

Answer (score 3):

It's both a qualifier and a keyword!

Answer (score 3):

'virtual' is a keyword and a qualifier. C++ is case sensitive and won't understand 'Virtual'.